# Deleting a wrong question after it has answers

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question about a piece of code not behaving as expected. After receiving a couple of answers I realized that the problem was caused by another part of the code not related to the question.

I feel this question might now be misleading for future readers. However, I can't delete it since it has already been answered. What should I do?

Comment: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vote/flag to close the question as "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".

Make sure to prominently comment about your findings for reviewers so that they know why they should close the question.